# preg_match all paragraphs in a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

The following string contains multiple `<p>` tags. I want to match the contents of each of the `<p>` with a pattern, and if it matches, I want to add a css class to that specific paragraph.

For example in the following string, only the second paragraph content matches, so i want to add a class to that paragraph only.

```
$string = '<p>para 1</p><p>نص عربي أو فارسي</p><p>para3</p>';
```

With the following code, I can match all of the string, but I am unable to figure out how to find the specific paragraph.

```
$rtl_chars_pattern = '/[\x{0590}-\x{05ff}\x{0600}-\x{06ff}]/u';
$return = preg_match($rtl_chars_pattern, $string);
```

Comment: Lol. Does someone have a link to that post addressing this?

Comment: Regex is generally unsuitable for parsing HTML. Use PHP's Document object.

Comment: @Carcigenicate link to what? Can you give an example of Document object? Thanks

Comment: There's a post here where someone emphasizes how regexes are unsuitable for parsing HTML. I don't have a link to it though. And just google for PHP'S Document object. It works similar to Javascript's DOM manipulation if you're familiar with that.

Comment: @Carcigenicate [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not) you go.

Comment: @LaurIvan That's not the exact one I was thinking of, but it does justice. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

- Create a capture group on the `<p>` tag
- Use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace)

https://regex101.com/r/nE5pT1/1

```
$str = "<p>para 1</p><p>نص عربي أو فارسي</p><p>para3</p>"; 
$result = preg_replace("/(<p>)[\\x{0590}-\\x{05ff}\\x{0600}-\\x{06ff}]/u", "<p class=\"foo\">", $str, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks, its very helpful but seems to be very strict, for example it does not match if there is any space at the end of the text.

Comment: Please have a look at your demo link, it also cuts the first character "ن" in the string. If you can kindly suggest how to fix that, i'd appreciate :)

Answer (score 2):

Use a combination of `SimpleXML`, `XPath` and regular expressions (regex on `text()`, etc. are only supported as of `XPath 2.0`).
The steps:

1. Load the **DOM** first
2. Get all `p` tags via an xpath query
3. If the text / node value matches your regex, apply a css class

This is the actual code:

```
<?php

$html = "<html><p>para 1</p><p>نص عربي أو فارسي</p><p>para3</p></html>";
$xml = simplexml_load_string($html);

# query the dom for all p tags
$ptags = $xml->xpath("//p");

# your regex
$regex = '~[\x{0590}-\x{05ff}\x{0600}-\x{06ff}]~u';

# alternatively:
# $regex = '~\p{Arabic}~u';

# loop over the tags, if the regex matches, add another attribute
foreach ($ptags as &$p) {
    if (preg_match($regex, (string) $p))
        $p->addAttribute('class', 'some cool css class');
}

# just to be sure the tags have been altered
echo $xml->asXML();

?>
```

See [a demo on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/SYM3x3). The code has the advantage that you only analyze the *content* of the `p` tag, not the `DOM` structure in general.