# preg_replace cuts first letter of the string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to add a class to `<p>` if it matches following expression using `preg_replace`.

Following code does that however it cuts the first letter of the string (rtl language). Notice the word `ہور`, the first character `ہ` is being cut. How that can be fixed ?

```
$str = "<p>para 1</p><p> ہور سنا کنجڑا </p><p>para3</p>"; 
$result = preg_replace("~\p{Arabic}~u", "<p class=\"foo\">", $str, 1);

echo $result;

//output
<p>para 1</p><p> <p class="foo">ور سنا کنجڑا </p><p>para3</p>
```

[**Demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e58de20d8d782747872a330457dbfe61e7251de0)

Comment: Kindly avoid [double postings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36018872/preg-match-all-paragraphs-in-a-string) (didn't one of the answers suit your needs?)

Comment: @Jan it was a completely different question, that's why I posted here as I remember reading in some other answer here that you should not ask multiple questions in same thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group the found character.

```
$str = "<p>para 1</p><p> ہور سنا کنجڑا </p><p>para3</p>"; 
$result = preg_replace("~(\p{Arabic})~u", "<p class=\"foo\">$1", $str, 1);
echo $result;
```

The `()` captures the found arabic character.
The `$1` adds it back into the replacement string.

Regex Demo: https://regex101.com/r/yN5vW3/1 vs. https://regex101.com/r/yN5vW3/2
PHP Demo: https://eval.in/537056

Comment: OP posted the very [same question twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36018872/preg-match-all-paragraphs-in-a-string)

Comment: And there is no need using capture groups since `$0` backreferences the whole match.

Answer (score 2):

[`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) doesn't "cut" the first letter of the string. It **replaces** it with the string you pass it as its second argument. This is what `preg_replace()` does for a living; it replaces fragments of strings :-)

There are several ways to tell it what you do. You can, for example, use the [sub-string that matches](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) into the replacement() string:

```
$result = preg_replace("~<p>(\p{Arabic})~u", '<p class="foo">$1', $str, 1);
```

Or you can use an [assertion](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php):

```
$result = preg_replace("~<p>(?=\p{Arabic})~u", '<p class="foo">', $str, 1);
```

Anyway, what you probably need is to replace `<p>` with `<p class="foo">` when the paragraph contain Arabic words. The code changes I suggested above already make use of this assumption.